# Gerar Sequência Registros com ClientDataSet (MultiUsuario)

Tags: delphi, firebird, tclientdataset

Galera eu tenho o seguinte cenário:

Tabela de Pedidos com Empresa, NumeroPedido que são chave primária. Demais campos como Cliente, Valor, ect...
Tenho um SQLQuery, um DataSetProvider e um ClientDataSet conectados apontando para esta tabela.

No evento OnBeforePost do ClientDataSet tenho uma função que retorna o sequencial do pedido.

Caso 2 usuários chamem post ao mesmo tempo, tenho erro de chave primária.

Tentei também criar uma trigger no banco para gerar esse sequêncial, porém também dá erro de chave primária.

Qual a forma mais segura de gerar esse sequencial?

Comment: Com certeza via trigger. Qual erro encontrou. Existe a opção de tratar no provider do delphi para obter da sequence

Comment: @Caputo via trigger também deu erro de chave primária. Achei estranho porque achava que não teria como isso acontecer.

Comment: pode postar o código de sua trigger? 12:00 eu posto a solução utilizando Sequence e o DataSetProvider se quiser

Comment: Na trigger eu tenho uma procedure que gera o sequencial. Seria algo parecido com: SELECT MAX(NUMERO_PEDIDO) + 1 FROM PEDIDO WHERE EMPRESA = :EMPRESA

Comment: @Caputo se puder colocar o exemplo de utilização de sequence com o DataSetProvider seria interessante. Obrigado!

Comment: o bicho pegou aqui ontem e estou liberando algumas coisas agora pela manhã. Mas não esqueci hehehe. Vou postar um exemplo de como fizemos em algumas aplicações aqui hooje ainda. Desculpe pela demora no feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, depois de alguns testes, cheguei num ponto que consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

Utilizo uma trigger before insert (Firebird) para gerar o sequencial. O código ficou assim:

```
  SELECT COALESCE(MAX(NUMERO_PEDIDO) + 1,1) FROM PEDIDO
   WHERE EMPRESA = NEW.EMPRESA 
    INTO NEW.NUMERO_PEDIDO;

  IF (EXISTS(SELECT NUMERO_PEDIDO FROM PEDIDO       
              WHERE EMPRESA = NEW.EMPRESA
                AND NUMERO_PEDIDO = NEW.NUMERO_PEDIDO)) THEN
  BEGIN
    SELECT COALESCE(MAX(NUMERO_PEDIDO) + 1,1) FROM PEDIDO
     WHERE EMPRESA = NEW.EMPRESA 
      INTO NEW.NUMERO_PEDIDO;
  END
```

Interessante que se deixar somente o primeiro bloco para gerar o sequencial sem o teste e duas ou mais pessoas incluírem um registro da o erro de chave primária.

Answer (score 0):

O seu erro é justamente utilizar o select Max() para fazer o incremento da chave. Como as transações vêem versões diferentes dos dados até serem comitadas, cada transação irá retornar o mesmo valor em Max(). Por isso você tem erro de chave primária. E o mesmo acontece nas triggers, já que elas enxergam apenas a versão dos dados dentro da sua transação. Ou seja, elas vão dar erro de chave primária mais cedo ou mais tarde.

Para autoincremento, existem duas estratégias:
A primeira e mais fácil é utilizando sequences/generator. 
Na trigger você pode escrever um codigo parecido com o que vem a seguir:

```
if (new.id = 0) then
  new.id = gen_id(meu_generator,1);
```

O único problema é que você pode não ter um número sequencial aí, uma vez que a cada chamada à gen_id, você incrementa o generator e perde um número (no caso da transação resultar em um rollback).

A segunda estratégia (e mais complicada) está em utilizar uma tabela de controle.
A utilização seria mais ou menos assim:

```
Você trava a tabela;
Resgata um número;
Libera a tabela.
```

E ao cancelar, você faria o movimento inverso:

```
Você trava a tabela;
Devolve um número;
Libera a tabela.
```

O problema é que você corre o sério risco de dar deadlock e a aplicação demorar a responder.

Como trata-se de um número de pedido, acho que o mais interessante para o seu caso seria utilizar a primeira estratégia, incrementando a sequence no processo de salvar.
E eu diria mais: faça isso na aplicação. Quando você for mudar de banco, será um trabalho danado tirar todas as triggers do banco ou fazer a portagem delas.